# how to change x-axis length of dimple chart

Tags: svg, d3.js, dimple.js

The tick labels and title of x-axis in a dimple chart is cut. I need to increase the length of the x-axis label (including tick label & title). Can anybody give inputs in accessing x-axis and increasing label height?

Answer (score 1):

Set the bounds of the chart within the svg area using SetBounds(). Rest of the svg area will be used for labels, legend and the rest.

Comment: API documents for `setBounds()`: https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.chart#setBounds